# authWithCustomToken callback is not calling in local nodejs application

Tags: authentication, firebase

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://caredeveloper.firebaseio.com");

var FIREBASE_SECRET = 'secret';

ref.authWithCustomToken(FIREBASE_SECRET, function (er, authData) {
   debugger 
   console.log("authenticated");
});
```

This callback function is getting called once move the code to production server.

But when i try debugging in local it is not calling the debugger.

(Using Visual studio code to debug.)

Comment: The callback is asynchronous. You're trying to insert a breakpoint in a callback -- I'm not sure if that'll work. There's also a missing semicolon after 'debugger'.

Comment: It may also be worth checking out: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html